# How can I add a button to my form

Tags: mobile, button

I can't find any button control to add to a form in my mobile application.  It's a standard mobile application with mobile emulator 6.0.

How can I add a button?

Comment: @Ben that is awesome. I am going to bookmark that site. bravo.

Comment: First off, LMGTFY links are not a proper comment or response to a question on any of the trilogy sites. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Secondly, if you wanted to use that site anywhere else, just go to http://lmgtfy.com/ and follow the instructions to create a lmgtfy link.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/MOB4DEVS01.aspx) article.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the questioner can clarify, but there are two different SDKs for Windows Mobile 6: Standard (for phones without touchscreens), and Professional (for phones with touchscreens).  In Standard, there is no button control as it is not supported.

However, custom controls are supported, and you can still create a button (IMHO it's needed, as you can still use one with a D-pad).  Go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172532.aspx) for an example on how to create one.